# Entity Framework Code First migrations adds a field not present in my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following model:

```cs
[Table("UsuariosHasPermisosEnUsuarios")]
public class UsuarioHasPermisoEnUsuario
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UHPEU_Unique", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int Permiso_Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UHPEU_Unique", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string UsuarioAsignado_Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UHPEU_Unique", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Usuario_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Permiso_Id")]
    public virtual Permiso Permiso { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioAsignado_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UsuarioAsignado { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Usuario_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have two references of ApplicationUser, so I have UsuarioAsignado and Usuario, the problem is when I execute the command `Add-Migration MigrationName` Entity Framework generates a third reference and foreign key of ApplicationUser:

```cs
CreateTable(
            "dbo.UsuariosHasPermisosEnUsuarios",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Permiso_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UsuarioAsignado_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    Usuario_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Permisos", t => t.Permiso_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.Usuario_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UsuarioAsignado_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => new { t.Permiso_Id, t.UsuarioAsignado_Id, t.Usuario_Id }, unique: true, name: "IX_UHPEU_Unique")
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id);
```

The problem ocurrs only because I have two references of that table, if I add only one, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Maybe try InverseProperty https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#relationship-attributes-inverseproperty-and-foreignkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this case you also have to configure another endpoint, i.e. `ApplicationUser` class with the help of `InversePropertyAttribute`:

```
public class ApplicationUser 
{
    //other properties...

    [InverseProperty("UsuarioAsignado")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioHasPermisoEnUsuario> UsuarioAsignados {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Usuario")]
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioHasPermisoEnUsuario> Usuarios {get;set;}
}
```